# python special charecter issue in 2.7 ( utf8' codec can't decode )

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

I have an array like this

```
 Address=['fâch','Pyrénées']
    print(Address)
```

Here array has the special character.How can I solve this

> error: utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Answer (score 1):

Just try this in python2.7 :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
Address = ['fâch', 'Pyrénées']
for i in Address:
     print i
```

The commented line should be in top of the file.

Comment: voooo. worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
Address=['fâch','Pyrénées']
for i in Address:
    value = unicode(i, 'utf-8')
    print value
```

This should help.